# How do I use Visual Studio 2010 MVC 3 for a non-html based project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, vxml

I'd like to use the Visual Studio 2010 MVC 3 framework for a web project that hosts [VXML](http://www.w3.org/TR/voicexml20/) and [CCXML](http://www.w3.org/TR/ccxml/) rather than HTML for telephony based applications.

MVC 3 seems ideally suited to this kind of application, and I think it's a great alternative to the more widely used jsp/Tomcat based applications that are generally used for VXML/CCXML. But there are a couple of annoyances:

1. The project tries to validate my .cshtml pages as HTML (understandably), or whatever target validation I set in Options>Text Editor>HTML>Validation>Target, but it forces me to have validation. I can't seem to find a way to switch it off altogether. Is there a way to switch it off and prevent hundreds of warnings? or better still, write my own custom validation for CCXML/VXML?
2. Is there a way to automatically set the content-type to "text/vxml" for all views without having to write `Response.ContentType = "text/vxml";` in every Action Method?

Comment: for point 2 - just use a base controller type and override, perhaps, OnResultExecuting or OnActionExecuting

Comment: @AndrasZoltan: ah yes, I should have thought of that myself... thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could write a custom view engine based on the Razor view engine and register a custom extension for your views:

```
public class VXMLViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
{
    public VXMLViewEngine()
    {
        ViewLocationFormats = new[] { "~/Views/{1}/{0}.vxml", "~/Views/Shared/{0}.vxml" };
        MasterLocationFormats = new[] { "~/Views/{1}/{0}.vxml", "~/Views/Shared/{0}.vxml" };
        PartialViewLocationFormats = new[] { "~/Views/{1}/{0}.vxml", "~/Views/Shared/{0}.vxml" };
        FileExtensions = new[] { "vxml" };
    }

    protected override IView CreateView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewPath, string masterPath)
    {
        controllerContext.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "text/vxml";
        return base.CreateView(controllerContext, viewPath, masterPath);
    }
}
```

and in Application_Start declare the custom extension:

```
RazorCodeLanguage.Languages.Add("vxml", new CSharpRazorCodeLanguage());
WebPageHttpHandler.RegisterExtension("vxml");
ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new VXMLViewEngine());
```

and the custom build provider in web.config that will recognize the `.vxml` extension:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
  <assemblies>
      ...
  </assemblies>
  <buildProviders>
    <add extension=".vxml" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
  </buildProviders>
</compilation>
```

Now you could use `.vxml` as extension for the views. Since Visual Studio doesn't recognize the `.vxml` extension, when you open a file with it, it won't bother you with warnings. And you could even create a custom VS plugin that could provide syntax highlighting and Intellisense for this custom extension.

Answer (score 2):

For 2 I recommend implementing a custom ActionResult that would set the ContentType automatically. There are many examples on stackoverflow and google that will show you exactly how to achieve this.

For 1 can't you just disable the "Show Errors" option under "Options>Text Editor>HTML>Validation"

Answer (score 1):

There is an [open source project called VoiceModel](http://voicemodel.codeplex.com/) that has a framework for creating VoiceXML applications using ASP.NET MVC 3, Razor and C#. It supports Reusable Dialog Components (RDC) and is extremely flexible.  There are [examples in the source code](http://voicemodel.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets) and documentation on how to use it on [this blog](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/).